# Separate an extremely long second solution into another answer or leave it in the original one?

Tags: discussion, answers

I answered [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507583/find-fn1-on-fx-1-sqrtx2n2/4508097#4508097) question yesterday. In my answer, I discuss 2 different evaluation techniques, one of which is long and partially incomplete. However, after thinking about it for a while, I have managed to complete the second solution as well. My issue here, is that the answer is already *very* big and with the addition of another edit, it will look very complicated (even though the first method isn't). Do I edit to extend the already existing answer or do I crop out the second solution, and put it in a new answer?

Comment: I didn't read your answers, so take this advice with that in mind, but I have posted a second, separate answer to a single question. If there's nothing tying to two together, then that gives people the opportunity to up- or down- vote each solution on their own merits. (I did add a note at the top of my first answer pointing to the second answer, as I thought the second was much superior.)

Comment: In this case you've already incorporated a fair amount of detail into your (existing) answer about taking the second approach.  Since the two approaches address the evaluation of the $r$-series, perhaps with extra rigor in your second approach, I think the best option here might be to edit your existing answer to include the complete second solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC ! The solutions here are a bit related, but while one seeks to remove pesky calculation by introducing a new series, the other embraces the peskiness and focuses on evaluating it. Is this sufficiently unrelated to warrant a new answer?

Comment: @hardmath That was actually my original thought process when I asked this question! However, the two methods are very different and imo could easily classify as separate answers as well; hence this question.

Comment: That's valid.  Other Answers have been posted to supplement yours.  But I can appreciate your desire to post your work for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @Cathedral - I'd say "go with your best guess, and don't worry that much, because someone's going to complain regardless of which you choose". :-)  My example that I remember has two very different approaches (algebraic grinding vs. nice picture), so I didn't have to deal with that. But thanks for asking, and raising the issue!

Comment: Thank you @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC!

Comment: If this were not appropriate, then posting a second answer on a question would not even be technically allowed.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi While true, the main reason I asked was to understand how unrelated two answers had to be to warrant splitting them. What I understood from the comments, is that one should do whatever seems more right based on context clues and how the majority react.